# Can't Access Textbox in ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, textbox, code-behind

I have a simple ASP.NET page with a button and a textbox, I want to click the button and have "Hello" appear in the textbox.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="SOM.aspx.cs" Inherits="SOM" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div><br />
        </div>
        <asp:Button ID="MyBtn" runat="server" Text="Click" OnClick="SearchBtn_Click" />
        <br />
        <br />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="268px"></asp:TextBox>
```

in the code behind I am able to use Intellisence to autocomplete `TextBox1.Text = "Hello";`

but then when I try to debug, the project fails to build saying

> The name TextBox1 does not exist in the current context

Is there a property that I need to set?

///Code behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Windows.Input;


public partial class SOM: System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void SearchBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //TextBox1.Text = "HI";
    }

    protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Post your code-behind. Post your entire `.cs` file.

Comment: Your CodeFile setting and Inherits are both correct? Check against your other pages to verify how they are setup

Comment: There is nothing wrong in this code. Post your code behind!!!

Comment: the class, codebehind file and Inherits now all say SOM. still the same error. everyone thinks this should work so unless there's another suggestion, I'm going to start a new project in case I messed up some settings somewhere that is causing this to break.

Comment: Is your code behind file really named  SOM.aspx.cs ? If the answer is no, there is no chance this is working !

Answer (score 1):

If any of the great answers here do not work, here's another solution that once caused me a few gray hairs, especially if you're using VS 2012.

If your project is a web application, delete the designer.cs file.  Then right click on the aspx file and select "Convert to Web Application".

For as great as Visual Studio is, sometimes these stupid WTF things drive me absolutely nuts.

Comment: I ended up deleting the SOM.aspx.cs file thinking I could re-add it back later but that is not the case in VS 2012. I ended up recreating a new project and now what I'm trying to do works. I've copied my existing SOM.aspx into the new project and created the methods to handle the events and now it's fine.... not sure what's up though.

Answer (score 0):

Your aspx page is not referencing the correct code behind.
In the head of your aspx page replace with

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="myName.aspx.cs" Inherits="myName" %>
```

That should work

Answer (score -1):

NOTE: I now know this isn't the problem, I but updated my answer in case it solves someone else's problem.

If you are using a namespace somewhere between your codebehind or the aspx page, you have to make it consistent.

I will use "MyProject" as a sample namespace.

```
namespace MyProject
{
    public partial class SOM: System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void SearchBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox1.Text = "HI";
        }

        protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

In your aspx page, change `Inherits="SOM"` to `Inherits="MyProject.SOM"`.

Comment: I have a few aspx pages and code behinds that do not belong to any namespace, and this working well...